# How to use tools:context to associtate Fragment files?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Recently I came across the use-case of using `tools:context` in my layout files for activities.
I learned that I can use it to associate an Activity class file to my layout file.

But how can I use it to associate a Fragment class file to any layout?

Bacuase as I have tried, it is only showing Activity list in autocomplete suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it doing like this:

Let's say `Relative layout` is your parent layout in your `fragment's` layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".Folder.Fragment"  >
```

Now this .xml file will be associated with your `.Fragment class` which is a fragment.

Comment: I have tried that but AutoComplete is not showing any Fragment names.
Let me type it manually and get back to you.

Comment: @Dhaval sure. But I have been using it like this and it works fine. If you want to show a fragment name in your autoComplete i don't think that's how you do it.

Comment: Thank you. The whole time I was waiting for my autocomplete to show Fragment names. And I was searching all over the internet for the solution. But once I have typed it manually as you said, it is working.

Answer (score 9):

There is a bug in Android Studio, you have to write it manually, it will appear red(indicating it's unresolved) until you finish typing, then it will appear in green

Answer (score 1):

Key point: Autocomplete is not showing name, manually enter it and it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Create a fragment with a layout file and see the layout file for `tools:context`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and typing in the fragment name didn't get the fragment name recognized in the tools:context=".NameFragment" statement.

What did work was first deleting both the class and xml files for that fragment and then:

1. Right click on the package name and choose New->Fragment->Fragment (Blank)
2. Enter in your fragment name (the layout name is automatically created on the same form) and click Finish.

This method created both the class and xml files at the same time. and at this point, the tools:context statement in my xml file had my fragment name automatically and was not red but green text (indicating that it was recognized). I'm seeing this on Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1.

Earlier I had created the xml file first and then created the class file (and had problems with the fragment class file name not being recognized by the tools:context statement).